# Aplicações desktop desenvolvidas em HTML CSS e Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, aplicação-desktop

Possuo uma aplicação Web MVC em .Net. Tenho a necessidade de migra-lá para desktop. Porem gostaria de manter a minha aplicação com as Views Web.

Sei que para app Android e IOS é possível reaproveitar as telas caso elas tenham sido desenvolvidas em HTML5.

Existem algum jeito de manter as minhas Views Web para plataforma desktop.

Comment: Eu olharia o código do [Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom) — ele é todo HTML + CSS + JavaScript. Você vai precisar fazer alguma coisa pra rodar um backend local, mas você pode usar a ideia do Atom como se fosse uma GUI pra esse servidor local.

Comment: Tente adicionar mais informações para facilitar a nossa ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesmo que seja possível, desaconselho desenvolver uma aplicação nativa para Windows com apenas Web Views - isto leva a uma péssima experiência da parte do utilizador.

Em vez disso, se o objectivo é deixar os utilizadores usarem a aplicação no seu computador sem acesso à internet, aconselho a instalar o website no computador local do utilizador, e o utilizador pode aceder ao site através do localhost.

Em vez de hospedar o site no IIS, experimenta usar [`Nancy`](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy) para *self-hosting*. Assim o utilizador final não precisa de ter IIS instalado.

A título de exemplo, recentemente usei o Plex (para fazer streaming de media). O plex instala um pequeno servidor no teu computador, e depois podes gerir a app através de `http://localhost:32400/web`.